# Создание миниатюр в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день!

При импорте записей WP появилась проблема с созданием миниатюр для фотографий.
Я использую в цикле функцию `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`, но на каком-то моменте скрипт прерывается(успевает создать миниатюры для нескольких десятков фоток), ошибок никаких не возвращает. Проверил память - с ней тоже все нормально, и timout'ы выставлены.
Который день бьюсь, не пойму в чем проблема.

```
foreach ($value['fotos'] as $i => $val) {

    $img       = str_replace('//', 'http://', $val['max']);
    $img_name  = $img_folder.basename($img);
    $img_title = basename($img);
    $attach_id = $id.'10'.$i;               

    if (!file_exists($img_name)) {
        downloadFile($img, $img_name);
    }

    $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($img_name), null);
    $post_img = array(
        'import_id'      => $attach_id,
        'post_author'    => 1,
        'post_parent'    => $id,
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'].'/property_images/'.$id.'/'.basename($img_name),
        'post_name'      => mb_strtolower($img_title),
        'post_title'     => $img_title,
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type']
    );

    if ($wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $attach_id))) {

        unset($post_img['import_id']);
        $post_img['ID'] = $attach_id;
        wp_update_post($post_img);

    } else {
        wp_insert_post($post_img);
    }

    if ( !is_wp_error($attach_id) ) {
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $img_name));
    }

    if ($i == 0) {
        update_metadata('post', $id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    }

    update_metadata('post', $attach_id, '_wp_attached_file', $img_name);

}
```

UPD - добавил код

Comment: Уверены, что скрипт не отваливается по таймауту? Попробуйте замерять время выполнения и писать лог в файл.

Comment: Уже проверял, время сбоя разное, варьируется от 100 до 130 секунд примерно

Comment: Больше всего подозрений у меня на память, но по наблюдениям видно что скрипт отваливается до его заполнения

Comment: Логи самого сервера смотрели?

Comment: Да, конечно, но там тишина.

Comment: Опытным путем я выяснил что скрипт останавливается в **wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php (стока 176)** - `$dims = image_resize_dimensions( $this->size['width'], $this->size['height'], $max_w, $max_h, $crop );`

Comment: Если скрипт останавливается без ошибок, то, вероятно, в этот момент были достигнуты какие-то лимиты на хостинге и сервер просто останавливает дальнейшее выполнение. Перед остановкой всегда обрабатывается одинаковое количество картинок?

Comment: Нет, количество картинок разное. Я всевозможные лимиты снял)

Comment: Я соберу больше данных и напишу.